# Get the coordinates of the objects found by a template

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, detection

I wanted to make a bot for a game that looks for a certain item on the floor, and then clicks on it. I managed to get the first part right (it even draws a rectangle around it) but whats embarrassing is that i cant get the coordinates of that object right. I use `cv2.matchTemplate` method. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pyautogui

img_bgr =  cv2.imread('gra.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template = cv2.imread('bones2.png', 0)

w, h = template.shape[:: -1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshhold = 0.90
loc = np.where( res >= threshhold)
for pt in zip(*loc[:: -1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_bgr, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h),(0, 255, 255), 2 )
    #here i wanted to move the mouse to the coordinates of a found item, however
    #i cant get these two right ↓        ↓
    pyautogui.moveTo(           ?     ,  ? ,duration=0.5)

cv2.imshow('znalezione', img_bgr)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried this:

```
 pyautogui.moveTo( (pt[0] *2  + w)/2  , (pt[1] *2 + h)/2 ,duration=0.5)
```

but this doesn't work at all. Can someone explain to me what pt is at all and how to get the coordinates?

Also here is a screen shot of what i achieved so far:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, both OpenCV and pyautogui uses the same coordinate system as illustrated with an example `1920x1080` resolution.

```
0,0       X increases -->
+---------------------------+
|                           | Y increases
|                           |     |
|   1920 x 1080 screen      |     |
|                           |     V
|                           |
|                           |
+---------------------------+ 1919, 1079
```

OpenCV's `cv2.rectangle` function takes the top left coordinates and the bottom right coordinates of the rectangle as parameters. Since you were able to draw the bounding box in your image, you have the correct coordinates of the ROI you want to examine. From the [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-movement) the `moveTo` function takes two parameters: `x` and `y`. Assuming you want to move the mouse to the center of the bounding box, you can do

```
pyautogui.moveTo(pt[0] + w/2, pt[1] + h/2, duration=0.5)
```

Comment: oh man i figured this like 5 seconds before reading this. (I got the same solution) Thing is pyautogui and OpenCV dont use the same coordinate system because the image isnt full screen. Do you there is any way to make them "kiss"?

Comment: Hmm? I believe they use the same coordinate system as shown in the illustration. Even if the image is full screen, `(0,0)` will be top left and `(max X, max Y)` will be bottom right. Could you elaborate on what you mean by kiss?

Comment: OpenCVs coordinate system starts from the top left corner of the image and pyautoguis from the top left corner of my screen. Can you somehow force pyautogui to use the OpenCVs system?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with pyautogui, maybe you should open a separate question for that

Answer (score 0):

first of all. you dont need so complex calculation

```
x=pt[0]
y=pt[1]
center_x = x + 0.5 * w
center_y = y + 0.5 * h
```

In terms of points, I don't see any issues. It's not the coordinate issue. I guess high chance, It's the pyautoui function issue. But I could not verify as I cant seems to install it on my PC.

based on example

```
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(100, 200, 2)
```

Try to call the same first to rule out the last parameter issue. If can, then its simple format isse.

If can not then it might be an image conversion issue. pyautogui function is using Pillow which is giving a format that must be adapted to work with opencv. So its either datatype RGB, BGR  or image coordinate issue(e.g opencv refer to image coordinate, and pyautogui uses desktop coordinate?).